# Sending post request to express server

Tags: angular, express, http, post

I have a function in my service that gets the users current location (latitude/longitude). I am trying to send the latitude and longitude to my server in order that I can add them to a query. However, my post request does not seem to be working. I have included my appInitializer module to show how this function is being called.

**eventServer.js**

```
router.get('/ticketmaster-events', (req, res) => {
/*   adding it to this query */
  axios.get('http://app.ticketmaster.com/discovery/v2/events.json?apikey=hneV7jzq6Uz7IyQC7GtEHz5s2nTsU6Jm&size=200')
  .then(res2 => {
    res.send(res2.data._embedded.events)
  })
  .catch(err => res.send(err))
  });

router.route('/currentLatLong').post((req, res, next) => {
  console.log("hello this test")
  try{
    res.end("response is " + req.body);
    console.log(req);
  }
  catch(err) {
    res.send(err);
  }
});
```

**google.service.ts**

```
export class GoogleService {
  uri = 'http://localhost:4000';
  public currentLat: number;
  public currentLng: number;
  public currentLatLong: any = [];

    getUserLocation() {
    /* locate the User */
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        console.log('good');
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
        this.currentLat = position.coords.latitude;
        this.currentLng = position.coords.longitude;
        this.data.latitudeSource.next(this.currentLat);
        this.data.longitudeSource.next(this.currentLng);
        const currentLatLong = {
          latitude : this.currentLat,
          longitude: this.currentLng
        };
        console.log(currentLatLong);

        return this.http.post(`${this.uri}/currentLatLong`, JSON.stringify(currentLatLong)/* , {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application-json'})} */
          ).subscribe(response => {
          console.log('your response is here', JSON.stringify(response));
           },
           error => {
             console.log('error occoured', error);
          });
      });
    } else {
      console.log('bad');
    }
  }
  constructor(private data: DataService, private http: HttpClient) { }
}
```

**appInitializer.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TicketMasterService } from '../../services/tmService/ticket-master.service';
import { GoogleService } from '../../services/googleService/google.service';

    export function fetchTmData(tmService: TicketMasterService) {
  return () => tmService.fetchTmData();
}

    export function getUserLocation(googleService: GoogleService) {
  return () => googleService.getUserLocation();
}

    @NgModule({
    imports: [HttpClientModule],
    providers: [
    TicketMasterService,
    GoogleService,
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: fetchTmData, deps: [TicketMasterService], multi: true },
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: getUserLocation, deps:[GoogleService], multi: true }
    ]
    })
    export class AppLoadModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont't know what error you are facing with, but it may work if you edit your GoogleService serice as below.

```
export class GoogleService {
  uri = 'http://localhost:4000';
  public currentLat: number;
  public currentLng: number;
  public currentLatLong: any = [];

  getUserLocation() {
    /* locate the User */
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        console.log('good');
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
        this.currentLat = position.coords.latitude;
        this.currentLng = position.coords.longitude;
        this.data.latitudeSource.next(this.currentLat);
        this.data.longitudeSource.next(this.currentLng);
        this.currentLatLong[0] = this.currentLat;
        this.currentLatLong[1] = this.currentLng;

       this.http.post(`${this.uri}/currentLatLong`, JSON.stringify(this.currentLatLong), {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application-json'})}
          ).subscribe(response=>{
           consol.log("your response is here")
           },
           error=>{console.log("error occoured")});

      });
    }
  }
  constructor(private data: DataService, private http: HttpClient) { }
}
```

You should make your `http requests` as `Observable`, and convert your object to string like the solution.

Comment: I get the error Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'HttpHeaders'.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the answer.I forgot closing parenthes of post method.

Comment: So, there is no error in your code, but if my logic is correct it should console.log the coordinate in the node terminal when the app initializes and it receives the post (eventServer.js), but I get no response from the post

Comment: you would share the log or error to solve your issue quickly.You sure your program is working in if statement blocks, so here `if (navigator.geolocation)` ?

Comment: Yes I received "good" in my console, so that fuction is executing, but if I check my network, the response I get from /currentLatlong is "response is [object Object]"

Comment: so, it is working! if you want to see detail of the object, type only `console.log(response)`

Comment: I get an empty object